# Display Excel VBA message box when a cell within a range changes AND meets a given criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help creating the Excel VBA to display a message box when a any input range to a calculated cell (cell with a formula in it) changes and meets a given criterion for the range.

For example, the range "B2" contains calculated cells which are a function of "A2", and if, upon updating the input, "A2", the recalculated cell, "B2" exceeds 20%, I want to warn the user with a message box.

Comment: `I need some help` - This site works much better when you show us what you've tried. Then we can help tweak it for you, if it's not working. See [FAQ]:www.stackoverflow.com/faq `Suggestions?` - That said, if you haven't tried anything, see `Worksheet_Change` Event in VBE editor, or the `Worksheet_Calculate` Event in the VBE Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Scott reminded me of the `Intersect` function which works out nicer than this `InRange` function

Edit2: This will allow you to have different rules for different ranges. If the cell which was changed by the user is within one of your controlled ranges then the validation rule for that range is called. Otherwise the function goes on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range '...
    Set Range1 = Me.Range("A1:A9")
    Set Range2 = Me.Range("B1:B9")
    '...

    If Not intersect(Range1, Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Rule for Range1
        If Target.Value > 0.2 Then   'put your condition here
            MsgBox "You exceeded 20%"
        End If

    ElseIf intersect(Range2, Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Rule for Range2...
    'elseif more ranges...
         'More rules...
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why the `InRange` Function? Why not just use `Intersect` method? `If Intersect(rangeToCompareTo, Target) Then`

Comment: Totally right! I knew there was something built in and I couldn't remember. I found that function...which is obviously not as good

Comment: This won't work for the user. As the 'Worksheet_Change` event will trigger only on changing the input cell. It will not trigger on the calculated cell change. You could modify it to by setting `rangeToCompareTo` to one or more of the input cells, and then change `If Target.Value > 0.2 Then` to 'If Range("myCalculateCell").Value > 0.2 Then` and it would work. However, that is a bit more convoluted than using 'Worksheet_Calculate`, at least with nothing else considered.

Comment: oh I see. So really it should be recomparing 20% to every cell in his range on every recalculate. not just the `target` range which triggered the event.

Comment: Well, yes and now. It just needs to evaluate the calculated cell(s). The OP wasn't fully clear if he needed to check one cell or several. See my answer for a clear explanation. Actually, now that I think about it, I think the best way is somewhere between yours and mine... because why check calculations that do not effect the cells he cares about?

Comment: To answer the last question, I need to it to check one cell within a range of cells based on the if the cell changed due to user input.

Comment: So if you had a situation where `B2` is a function of `A1` and the user changes `A1`. would you want the macro to check the validity of `A1` or `B2`?

Comment: @jmonger - `I need to it to check one cell within a range of cells` - you don't need to `check 1 within a range`... you can just check the 1 cell! See my edited answer below.

Comment: @jmonger I updated again. Maybe that is more like what you need? One of these answers has got to do it! :)

Comment: @Brad - I am pretty sure I gave it to him already and it is very simple and easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This code will only trigger if your input cells change, which is better than just using 'Worksheet_Calulate`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRange As Range

myRange = Range("B1:B2") '-> assumes input cells are in B1:B2

If Intersect(myRange, Target) Then

    '-> assumes calculated cell in A1
    If Range("A1").Value > 0.2 Then MsgBox "Above 20%"

    '-> to loop through many cells, do this
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Range("A1:A10")

        If cel.Value > 0.2 Then MsgBox cel.Address & " Above 20%"
        Exit For

    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This gets me 90% of the way there. Is there a way to look only at the cell that just recalculated within a range and not the entire range as a trigger for the MsgBox? I only want the popup for newly calculated outliers, not every outlier after every calculation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I just thought of that. See my edited answer.

Comment: @jmonger - my edited code is based on a change in the input cell. So if that cell changes, it looks at the affected (calculated) cells to see if the percent is greater.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the workbook sheet change event that is checking for a change in the A1 cell in sheet 1

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
    'check to ensure we are working in the correct Sheet
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        'check to see how many cells have been targeted
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Cells.Address = "$A$1" Then
                'check to see what value has been entered into the cell
                If Target.Value = 20 Then
                    MsgBox "Alerting the user"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```