# how to get alert box or message box when i try to change the value of a cell in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get a alert box or message box when any one changes the value of a cell in excel from "Yes" to "No".
Can any one help me in acheiving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Excel VBA message box when a cell within a range changes AND meets a given criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426870/display-excel-vba-message-box-when-a-cell-within-a-range-changes-and-meets-a-giv)

Comment: Except that was closed for being not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.  It's going to do two things:

- Save the value of the selection, in a `_SelectionChange` event.
- Launch a separate `_Change` event and get the updated value.
- If the selection WAS a "YES", AND the new change is "NO" (checks for Upper-Lower)
- Display a Message

**The variable needs to be outside the scope of either change event.**

```
Dim oldValue As Variant
```

**The selection change event:**

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    oldValue = Target.Value

End Sub
```

**The change event:**

```
Public Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If LCase(oldValue) = "yes" And LCase(Target.Value) = "no" Then
        MsgBox ("The value of " & Target.Address & " has changed from " & oldValue & " to: " & Target.Value)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peege, actually my question is when Im changing the values in cells from yes to no, I should get a messgae / alert box, not by running the macro. Can you suggest me for that

Comment: @JuluruKarthik - maybe you should try the suggested answer instead of assuming it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim YourCell As Range
Set YourCell = Cells(1, 1)

If YourCell.Value = "No" Then
MsgBox ("YourAllert"), vbExclamation

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Liniel, actually my question is when Im changing the values in cells from yes to no, I should get a messgae / alert box, not by running the macro. Can you suggest me for that

Comment: @JuluruKarhik if you won't use macro, so how you want to trigger your alert?